# Some statistics related to the abc conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture, experimental-mathematics

We did some statistics about the 14 million good abc triples below 10^18
taken from Bart de Smith site.

This was examining just the top of the iceberg, since the
interesting triples grow very likely well above 10^18.

We were interested in $\#\{(a,b,c) :a \le c^\alpha\}$ for real $\alpha$,
as $a,b,c$ are taken from the good triples, assuming $a < b$.

Here are the numbers:

```
alpha , #a<=c^alpha in percents
0 (a=1) 0.31
1/4     2.38
1/2    11.75
3/4    38.59
9/10   70.34
```

The arithmetic mean of $\log{a}/\log{c}$ is 75.894%,
which is very close to $3/4$.

We did the same computation for the 234 (give or take few)
high quality triples (quality > 1.4) and the data is:

```
0    4.27
1/4 16.24
1/2 35.47
3/4 68.38
9/10 91.03
```

The arithmetic mean of $\log{a}/\log{c}$ is 58%.

Can we get some heuristic arguments about the distribution
of good abc triples?

Comment: 58% is not far from $\gamma$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I strongly doubt this holds in general, we are examining very small set.

Comment: "good" = $\operatorname{rad}(abc)<c$?

Comment: @WillSawin Yes. Or in other words quality >1.

Comment: If one assumes $\operatorname{rad}(a), \operatorname{rad}(b), \operatorname{rad}(a+b)$ behave as independent random variables, the key quantity is understanding the number of $n \approx N$ with $\operatorname{rad}(n) \approx n^\alpha$. Surely this must be known/studied. I think the highest-order terms in the asymptotic are $n^\alpha e^{ \sqrt{\log n}}$ but I don't know what the next ones are.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN also note that the threshold of 1.4 used here is completely arbitrary...

Comment: @WillSawin May I have your opinion about abc and surjective polynomials:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332189/abc-conjecture-and-surjective-polynomials